# get the value and the key from input array by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have code something like that

```
<input type="text" name="item_qty[0]">
<input type="text" name="item_qty[1]">
<input type="text" name="item_qty[2]">
<input type="text" name="item_qty[3]">
```

and I want to specify by JQuery which input from the array has been changed (0,1,2,3) and get its value.

I tried the below code but I couldn't complete it I need to get the array key ($i) and the input value .

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {     
      $('input[name=item_qty[$i]]').change(function(){


      });
  });
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input').on('input',function(i,v){
console.log("index of input is " + $(this).index())
console.log("name of input is " + $(this).attr('name'))


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="item_qty[0]">
<input type="text" name="item_qty[1]">
<input type="text" name="item_qty[2]">
<input type="text" name="item_qty[3]">
```

You can use the index of the input by using `.index()`

Comment: thanks but what if I want to get the key only without the whole name for example 0 instead of item_qty[0]

Comment: use trhis `$(this).index()`

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event only fires once the text-input is blurred (the user tabs, or clicks, out of that `<input>`); if that's what you want to happen then:

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('change', function(e) {
  // e: is a reference to the event.

  var index = $(this).index(),
      name = this.name;

  console.log("Name: " + name + ", index: " + index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="item_qty[0]" />
<input type="text" name="item_qty[1]" />
<input type="text" name="item_qty[2]" />
<input type="text" name="item_qty[3]" />
```

Or, in plain JavaScript it's still relatively easy (albeit somewhat more verbose):

```js
// a simple utility function to retrieve the element's index:
function getIndex(node) {

  // assigning the node to the 'current' variable:
  var current = node,

    // initialising a 'count' variable at 0:
    count = 0;

  // while there is a current node, and that current node
  // has a previousElementSibling (a previous sibling that
  // is an HTMLElement):
  while (current && current.previousElementSibling) {

    // increment the count:
    count++

    // assign the previous HTMLElement sibling to
    // the current variable and repeat:
    current = current.previousElementSibling;
  }

  // return the final value of the count:
  return count;
}


// a simple named function to retrieve the relevant details:
function getDetails() {

  // caching the 'this' into the 'node' variable:
  var node = this;

  // logging the details (you could also return here):
  console.log({

    // the name of the element node:
    'name': node.name,

    // the index of the element node:
    'index': getIndex(node),

    // and the value of the element node
    // (to show how to access existing
    // other properties of the node,
    // although that wasn't specified in
    // the question):
    'value': node.value
  });
}


// creating an Array from the Array-like HTMLCollection returned
// by document.querySelectorAll(), and iterating over that Array
// using Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')).forEach(function(input) {
  // 'input', the first argument, is a reference to the
  // current Array-element of the Array over which
  // we're iterating.

  // here we assign the named function (note the lack of
  // parentheses) as the 'change' event handler:
  input.addEventListener('change', getDetails);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.4em 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item_qty[0]" />
<input type="text" name="item_qty[1]" />
<input type="text" name="item_qty[2]" />
<input type="text" name="item_qty[3]" />
```

References

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors (`[attr]`, `[attr=value]`...)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).
  - [`While (...)` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).
- jQuery:

  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).